# Modal in Angular from jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to call a modal from jQuery which will invoke a page which would be an Angular based. 
I started with a small 2 page application. This is my folder structure:

```
<main folder>
----index.html
----index.js
----blah.js
----blah.html
----style.css
```

In index.html i load angular before jquery
index.html:

```
<body>
<h1>jQuery + jQuery UI Template</h1>
<p>Click the button; I dare you.</p>
<p>
  <button id="clickme">Click me</button>
</p>
<!-- Put your html here! -->
<div id='somediv'></div>
</body>
```

Index.js:

```
$(function(){
var url = './blah.html';
$("button").button().click(function(e){
   $("#somediv").load(url).dialog({modal:true}); 
   });
});
```

blah.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

blah.html:

```
 <html ng-app="plunker">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Right now there is no error in console but Angular does not work either. Any pointers?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap look here for manual initialization.

Comment: thanks @PetrAveryanov but that is also not working.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery != Angular JS

use $http directive